# Get second item with preg_match in php

Tags: php, html

I am getting text between two tags with PHP (from a HTML).

a sample code i use is this :

```
function GDes($url) {
    $fp = file_get_contents($url);
    if (!$fp) return false;

    $res = preg_match("/<description>(.*)<\/description>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);

    if (!$res)  return false; 

    $description = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
    $description = trim($description);
    return $description;
}
```

It gives between the `description` tags, But my problem is that if the page have to `description` tags, it will give the first one that i don't need it.

I need to get the second one.

For example, If my HTML is this :

```
<description>No need to this</description>
<description>I NEED THIS ONE</description>
```

I need to give the second description tag with that function above.

What changes the function needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all` instead. It will create an array with all matches.
You can keep your code as is, just replace `preg_match` with `preg_match_all`.

Then you have to use `$title_matches[1][1]` instead of `$title_matches[1]` in your `preg_replace` call, since the `$title_matches` is now a multidimensional array.

Comment: Tnx, How to get the second one with that function?

Comment: `$title_matches[1][1]` for the match only of the 2nd match.

Comment: @Pafo this is a place for people to help / volunteer, not to do your work for you.

Comment: added explanation though, you are alomst there :)

Comment: @iswinky If i don't know what to do then ? ^_^

Comment: @MarcAntonDahmen TNX for Answer Dear Marc <3